# (C++) Infinite zeros with the addition operator in a small loop

Tags: c++, loops

i have a little problem with this small piece of code;
If i use the ++ operation (x++) it works fine, but if i write "x + 1" it breaks and causes an infinite loop of zeros.

The code:

```
int x = 0;

while (x <= 20)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    x + 1;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `x + 1` does nothing.  It evaluates an expression and throws the value away.  You'd want either `x += 1;` or `x = x + 1;`.

Comment: Check the compiler warnings. There may be a warning. If not turn up the warning level. Do not ignore warnings. They are the first line of defense against logic errors, and the more work you can get the compiler to do for you, the less work you have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a value of a variable you must* use an `=`.
This : `x + 1` is NOT the same as `x = x + 1` or `x += 1` or `x++`.

When you add that x plus to your code you are never changing the value of x.
`x + 1` simply returns a temporary value of the result. Where as the other three listed about will change the value of x instead of creating a temporary value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the differences between different statements related to increment as below.

- x++ means x = x + 1; which means copy the value of x into temporary
  register, increment the value by 1 and write that register value back
  into x.
- x + 1 means, copy the value of x into temporary register, increment
  the value by 1. You are not assigning the value back to x. So x value
  won't be changed.

So in your while loop, x value is not being changed which is reason for infinite loop.